# Updated EF 5 to 6 - can I safely remove old folders?

Tags: entity-framework

I started my solution with Entity Framework 5. Then I updated it to EF 6 with help of NuGet. In solution directory is a `packages` folder, and inside are:

- EntityFramework.5.0.0
- EntityFramework.6.0.0-beta1
- EntityFramework.6.0.1

Can I remove 5.0.0 and 6.0.0-beta1 folders? Or will that break something for me or other team members? The solution is under Source Control (TFS).
Or maybe there are some other files (eg. package.config), that I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be safe as long as you don't have any project referencing them. The NuGet package upgrade should've taken care of that (Unless someone manually added reference directly to those assemblies outside of NuGet that is...)

Worst case, you just have to re-download the missing package.

If you'd rather be safe, you can always move those folders outside the solution, and if anything breaks, move them back in.